# Calculate the center point of a arc wedge

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I've drawn an arc made up of individual wedges:

[image: wedges example]

I need to draw an image at the center of each wedge. Using `drawImage()` I need to find the canvas coordinates of the center of each wedge.

Initially I thought I could begin drawing another arc that only reaches to the center of the wedge and retrieve the context position, but I don't think that's possible.

I'm no math wiz and I assume this will involve some trig, but I'm not quite certain where to start here. Any advice?

Comment: Is the arc always a half circle? Does it always have 5 wedges or could it have 3 or 6?

Comment: What exactly is a *center* of a wedge?

Comment: Also, will you want to rotate the image to match the arc? or will they maintain orientation and just be positioned over in the right places?

Comment: In this case, a half circle with 5 wedges! And I guess the 'center' of a wedge would be half the distance between the start and end angles, and half the distance between its inner and outer radii. Images shouldn't rotate - they'll maintain orientation and be positioned over the right places.

Comment: It's easiest to integrate the center point calculations to the wedge creation, can you show how you're creating the wedges? Notice, that you don't need the center of arc here, maybe edit the confusing title.

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle with some code? you'll get a faster response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way you can do this:

1. Calculate the average *radius* by `ar = (r1 + r2) / 2`. This will give the center perpendicular to arc's center point.
2. Calculate the average *angle* by `aa = (a1 + a2) / 2`. This will give the center point between the two wedge edges. **Note** that this has edge cases (no pun) where the second angle may be smaller than the first angle which will cause the average to "wrap around". Always use `a1` for the smallest angle and if `a2` is smaller add 360° (or 2 x π in radian) to `a2`.
3. With these two values we can calculate center x and y using:  
   `x = centerX + cos(aa) * ar;
   y = centerY + sin(aa) * ar;`

## Examples

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var r1 = 100;                                         // inner radius
var r2 = 140;                                         // outer radius
var a1 = Math.PI + 0.1;                               // start angle
var a2 = Math.PI + 0.6;                               // end angle
var cx = 150;                                         // arc center point
var cy = 150;

// render the wedge
ctx.arc(cx, cy, r1, a1, a2);
ctx.arc(cx, cy, r2, a2, a1, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

// calculate center point
var r = (r1 + r2) * 0.5;                              // avr. radius
var a = (a1 + (a2 > a1 ? a2 : a2 + Math.PI*2)) * 0.5; // avr. angle + special case

var x = cx + Math.cos(a) * r;                         // use angle and radius for
var y = cy + Math.sin(a) * r;                         // new center point in wedge

// plot center point
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(x-1, y-1, 3, 3);
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

Edge case:

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var r1 = 100;
var r2 = 140;
var a1 = Math.PI * 2 - 0.2;
var a2 = 0.4;
var cx = 150;
var cy = 75;

// render the wedge
ctx.arc(cx, cy, r1, a1, a2);
ctx.arc(cx, cy, r2, a2, a1, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

// calculate center point
var r = (r1 + r2) * 0.5;
var a = (a1 + (a2 > a1 ? a2 : a2 + Math.PI*2)) * 0.5;

var x = cx + Math.cos(a) * r;
var y = cy + Math.sin(a) * r;

// plot center point
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(cx, cy, 200, 1);
ctx.fillText("0°", cx, cy - 2);
ctx.fillRect(x-1, y-1, 3, 3);
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```